# Skip and Take email from server MailKit

Tags: c#, mailkit

I have some problem. I have users who have so many many email ( ~ 5000 emails)
I try to get only 20 emails with Skip and Take. (I'm trying to do endless scrolling) But my code is so long because I get all ids of emails and after it, I call FetchAsync method and call Skip and Take.
How can I get only 20 emails with summaries info from email server?
I try to get count of allIds var = 20

```
await folder.OpenAsync(FolderAccess.ReadOnly).ConfigureAwait(false);
var allIds = await folder.SearchAsync(SearchQuery.All).ConfigureAwait(false);
var fetch = await folder.FetchAsync(allIds,
                MessageSummaryItems.Envelope | MessageSummaryItems.Flags | MessageSummaryItems.Full |
                MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId | MessageSummaryItems.PreviewText | MessageSummaryItems.BodyStructure).ConfigureAwait(false);
var summaries = fetch
                .OrderByDescending(c => c.Date)
                .Skip(offset)
                .Take(limit)
                .ToArray();
```

Comment: so you need to do `Skip` and `Take` on step getting your ids

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution:

```
await folder.OpenAsync(FolderAccess.ReadOnly).ConfigureAwait(false);

var ids = (await folder.SortAsync(SearchOptions.All, SearchQuery.All, new[] {OrderBy.ReverseDate}).ConfigureAwait(false)).UniqueIds
    .Skip(offset)
    .Take(limit)
    .ToArray();

var items = await folder.FetchAsync(ids,
    MessageSummaryItems.Envelope | MessageSummaryItems.Flags | MessageSummaryItems.Full |
    MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId | MessageSummaryItems.PreviewText | MessageSummaryItems.BodyStructure).ConfigureAwait(false);
```